# How to make the records clickable

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to make my records clickable? for example the names of my records..so that when i click them i will be redirected to a new page where i can print that record and its other info.. here's where my table looks like

```
    <div id="vi">
    <div id = "search_field">
    <?php 
    $search_field = array('name'=>"search_field",'placeholder'=>"Search booking : Type the name of guest.");
    echo form_open('site/view');
    echo form_input($search_field);
    echo form_submit('search',"Search");
    ?>
    </div>

    <?php 
     $this->table->set_heading("Name","Nationality","Contact Number","Number of Guest","Date of Arrival","Package","Other Request","Delete Record","Edit");
    $qry = $this->db->like('name',$search_key)->get('booking');
    if ($qry->num_rows > 0) {
    foreach ($qry->result() as $row) {
      $this->table->add_row($row->name,$row->nationality,$row->contactnum,$row->number_of_guest,$row->date,$row->package,$row->request,anchor('site/delete/'.$row->id, 'Delete'),anchor('site/update/'.$row->id, 'Edit'));
 }
 }
  else{
echo "No records found!";
 }

  echo $this->table->generate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?php 
$this->table->add_row("<a href='yourpage.php?name=$name' target='_blank'>$row->name
</a>",$row->nationality,$row->contactnum,$row->number_of_guest,
$row->date,$row->package,$row->request,anchor('site/delete/'.$row->id,
'Delete'),anchor('site/update/'.$row->id, 'Edit'));
?>
```

Comment: doesn't work..it only made the table heading "Name" a link.. it should be the names in the records..

Answer (score 0):

If the datas comes form you DB , you'll do something like that :

```
<?php
 $query = "SELECT ..... FROM....";
 $res = mysql_query($query);
// HEADER
$this->table->set_heading("Name","Nationality","Contact Number","Number of Guest","Date of Arrival","Package","Other Request","Delete Record","Edit");

while($res=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $id = mysql_fetch_array("id");
    $name = mysql_fetch_array("name");
    $nationnality = mysql_fetch_array("nationnality");
    $guests = mysql_fetch_array("guests");
    $date = mysql_fetch_array("date");
    //...
    $this->table->add_row("<a href='secondPage.php?id=$id'>".$name."<a>",$nationnality,$guests,$date);

}
?>
```

you query get infos in the db, and for each result you create a new line. 
then , you need a link with something to identify your line from the others , so each line have a different id .

Comment: doesn't work..it only made the table heading "Name" a link.. it should be the records name..

Comment: In your table , instead of this value , you are gonna to write php vars or just hard coded text ?

Comment: when i click a name in my table i want it to be redirected to a new page so i can print it..

Comment: Sure , but these names , where do they come from ? Database ? or you are gonna do add all of them manually in your table ?